# Active tab in nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an active tab in my nav bar. I have used javascript for this. I have the javascript in my code. I can't find the reason why it isn't working

```js
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("active-link");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("button");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("active");
    this.className += "active";
  })
}
```

```css
.active-link {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 10rem;
  left: 25%;
  margin: 100px -5px;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: ease;
}

.button:hover {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="active-link" id="active-link">
  <li>
    <a class="button">him</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="button">her</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="button">xyz</a>
  </li>

</div>
```

active links that are padded. Reference can be something like the active tabs in new balances website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vadar

I have added the new function for removing class from all current active tabs.
It will be active one tab at a time.

Here is the solution:

```js
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("active-link");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("button");


function removeClass(elems, className) {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(elems), function(el) {
    el.classList.remove(className);
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    removeClass('.button', 'active')
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.active-link {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 10rem;
  left: 25%;
  margin: 100px -5px;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: ease;
}

.button:hover,
.active {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="active-link" id="active-link">
  <li>
    <a class="button active">him</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="button">her</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="button">xyz</a>
  </li>

</div>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the response. Your code is working. However, is there a way that the first li is pre-selected ("him" in this case)? Like, when the code is run, "him" has to be active already. Thanks again!

Comment: I have added the active class on 'HIM' (first tab) updated the code as well.
Please review.

Thank :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because nothing is active by default.
Try adding an active element other wise the code :

```
 var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("active");
```

Will give an error.

Also, do check your JS console to find the error and figure out on your own :)